# Prometheus - How to update prometheus config via http serivce discovery to integrate with confluent cloud metrics

Tags: prometheus, metrics, service-discovery, confluent-cloud

I have integrated confluent cloud metrics using prometheus.
I am trying to update prometheus config via http service discovery.
The JSON Format used is as below

```
[
{
"target": ["xyz"],
"labels": {"__metrics_path_": "abc",
           "__param_resource.kafka.id":"k1"
          }
}
]
```

I am getting error **"__param_resource.kafka.id"** is not a valid label, as prometheus does not allow dot(.) in label name.
Also what if I need to add multiple values in kafka id, How can I do this two things in http service discovery.